# Which pattern should I use with preg_match_all() to extract an amount in this string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Would like to extract an amount in the following string:

```
£5000 per Night - 1 bedroom - Serviced Apartment
```

Any idea on how to do it using preg match all ?

I'm using this pattern:

```
preg_match_all("|£(\d)|U",$string,$matches);
```

but it only fetches 5 instead of 5000

**what if it's £15,000 could be extract it with the comma ?**

thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\d+` instead of `\d`. Otherwise, it'll only match a single digit. `+` means 'one or more'.

```
preg_match_all("|£(\d+)|U",$string,$matches);
```

(For more details on how repetition works in regular expressions, see [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).)

---

An expression that allows commas as well, and makes sure that they aren't in weird spots (e.g. `,500`):

```
preg_match_all("|£(\d+(?:,\d+)*)|U",$string,$matches);
```

Comment: what if it's £15,000 could be extract it with the comma ?

Comment: Then use `[\d,]+` to allow for commas as well, or `\d+(?:,\d+)*` if you want to ensure there's at least one digit on either side of potential commas.

Answer (score 3):

Use `+` to match 1 or more instances of `\d`

```
preg_match_all("|£(\d+)|U",$string,$matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've missed the recursion `preg_match_all('|£(\d+)|U', $string, $matches)` (note the '+' after the `\d`)

**Update to reflect comma in price**

If you're matching a price with commas or periods, the RegEx would look like `|£([\d,\.]+)|` - as a basic example. The `[ ... ]` square brackets allow you to match a set or characters rather than just a single type of character - so in this instance it's any number, a comma or a period. `[0-9,\.]+` would work as well (you need to escape the period as it's a special "any character" match in Regular Expressions).